# Select text in HTML with GWT mouse events sunk

Tags: ios, gwt, mouseevent, selection

I have a `<div>` with some text and I would like the user to be able to natively select the text. The issue is that when I attach any mouse event handler to the element or it's parent (besides document element) the selection won't work any longer.

This could be observe on the site linked below. If you sink mouse events the selection won't work for the first line.

http://rafalrybacki.com/lab/selection_ios/

What happens after clicking "sink mouse events" is:

```
main.sinkEvents(Event.MOUSEEVENTS);
```

Checked with iOS5.

I would like make the text selecting work (keeping the mouse events). How to do this?

Comment: Can you try to clarify your question a little bit ? Maybe asking a direct question

Comment: @Jean-Michel Garcia - thanks, I've added detailed question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? From the end-users view ? I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you want to do

Comment: If I add mouse event handler to the elements the browser's native selection on iOS is not working. I would like to keep the event handlers attached to the elements and have the selection working.

Comment: what do you call *browser native selection* ?

Comment: If you have some text in the web browser and mouse down somewhere in the area of the page and then mouse up somewhere else in the area of the page - the text and other resources are selected and marked usually with blue color. The same happens on mobile devices when you touch some area in the web page for a longer time.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question, and also post some small relevant code. Otherwise it will be difficult to help you